# Did anyone else get a charater nicknamed Santa on Christmas Eve?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I was playing Xcom late last night (12-24-12) and the reward for the mission I was playing was a Support class Captain. Once I finished the mission and set his skills I noticed his nickname. It is "Santa." Is this an awesome coincidence or a timed easter egg like in Batman Arkham City?

Comment: Could you show to us (at least for me xD) what's the easter egg from `Batman Arkham City` ? I don't know him =) (And I'm not sure if my question in this comment, should be considered a question on Arqade or not)

Comment: @Michel probably the Calendar Man's monologues on 12 various dates.

Answer (score 2):

This would appear to be the case. [See this thread on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/15gf1e/playing_late_last_night_and_the_aliens_ruined/)

Comment: You never answered his question. He said this or that and you said YES.

Comment: @Ender then maybe he should synch the question title and body.